# Multiple Facebook share button/link on the same page refering different TITLE & LINK

Tags: facebook

I need to create a "contest" page where user will be asked to submit picture.

After that, they should be able to share their picture on FB, Twitter, G+, Pinterest, etc for other people to come and vote.

I want the page to be displayed as a jQuery gallery and whenever people select a thumbnail, the bigger picture open with the associated vote and "share" button.

When a user share an image, I want a specific TITLE & URL associated with that particular image... something like "http://www.mysite.com/contest.html#picture1"... or "http://www.mysite.com/contest.html#picture2"

How is this possible if I only have one page?

I wouldn't have problem if I could use the old "facebook.com/sharer.php" with parameters... but it seems that the Open Graph Protocol is "overiding" the sharer.php parameters....

Works fine with Twitter and Pinterest... I might have the same problem with Google+.

Excuse my bad english, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, set up a (“dummy”) page for each picture, and fill it with the appropriate OG tags … and have your users like *that*. And then put a JS redirect into that page, so that users following the link when it’s shared on Facebook will get to the “real” address you want them to end up at.

*(Btw., IMHO this is what happens too often these days when people think doing everything client-side and client-side* only *is so “fancy” and that a “good” and “modern” site requires all that AJAX/one-page-only nonsense instead of a real* good and working *URL structure, and then are not able to handle all that this implies properly …)*

Comment: Thanks for your input... I agree with you but for this purpose, I don't want user to go back and forth between the gallery and a specific image page... Our targeted customers are usually older and not so familiar with browsing so I preferred the "one page only" design... 
Also, isn't looking at a gallery on the same page easier to better compare picture and get a good idea rather than browsing trough URL... Gallery -> Image 1 -> Back to Gallery -> Image 2 -> Back to Gallery -> Image 3, etc...

Comment: I’m not saying you can’t set up a page this way for user comfort – but it should always be set _on top_ of a working site structure.